# Open many external links in many new tabs on click

Tags: html

You'd think I'd be able to work this out from Google, but I've had no luck.

I'm building a content aggregator, imagine a list of links to external sites. Every time I click a link I would like to open a new tab.

At the moment I have target="blank" but what happens is the first link opens a new tab, and all of the subsequent clicks just overwrite the newly opened tab - opening a grand total of 1 new tabs.

As opposed to what I want which is if I click 5 external links, it opens 5 new tabs.

Other aggregators like Digg.com and Delicious somehow manage it, but their a tags's are no different to mine.

Thanks folks

Edit:

Here's how the links are at the moment:

```
<a class="header" href="/links/56bae5109e1b937548000307/go" rel="nofollow" target="blank">Finding Dory: new posters land</a>
```

Comment: You will have to show us your code.  We can't diagnose a problem we can't see.

Comment: Apologies @JimGarrison. I've added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, just make sure there is an underscore `_` in front of `blank` as the value:

```
<a class="header" href="/links/56bae5109e1b937548000307/go" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Finding Dory: new posters land</a>
```

- This is because `_blank` is an actual special word that instructs the browser to open new tab or window. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp):

> _blank    Opens the linked document in a new window or tab

- whereas you had just `blank` which will be interpreted as a specific window target name, thus all links kept opening to that target.

Answer (score 1):

You should try,

```
  <a class="header"  rel="nofollow"  target="_blank" href="http://your_url_here.html">Finding Dory: new posters land</a>
```

- If you set the target attribute to "`_blank`", the link will open in
  a new browser window or a new tab.
- "`blank`" causes the result what are you experiencing now,

  > I have target="blank" but what happens is the first link opens a new
  >   tab, and all of the subsequent clicks just overwrite the newly opened
  >   tab - opening a grand total of 1 new tabs.

  like what you said before.